# I can't access the value I want in my GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm building an appointment system using AWS Amplify, TypeScript, and React that is based on clients that have many jobs, and jobs that have many appointments.

I have a page with a table on it that contains all the jobs in the jobs database. I want a column that displays the client name that the job belongs to, like this:

[image: job table with 2 jobs in it with the last column containing the client first and last name]

However the `listJobs` query in `queries.ts` that was generated from my GraphQL schema only allows me to obtain the client ID (via `{job.clientJobsId}` in my code):

```js
export const listJobs = /* GraphQL */ `query ListJobs($filter: ModelJobFilterInput, $limit: Int, $nextToken: String) {
  listJobs(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      summary
      description
      jobAddress
      status
      createdBy
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      clientJobsId
      __typename
    }
    nextToken
    __typename
  }
}
` as GeneratedQuery<APITypes.ListJobsQueryVariables, APITypes.ListJobsQuery>;
```

[image: job table with 2 jobs in it with the last column containing the client id for each]

When I run `amplify mock api` and explore my API in the browser, it allows me to create a query that includes the client name:

[image: sidebar of graphQL explorer showing the client name is able to be selected within the listJobs query]

**Why does the generated `listJobs` query in queries.ts differ from the graphQL explorer, and how do I get the client name into the column?**

## Things I've tried

- Printing the `jobs` state object to the browser console, which looks like this:
  [image: the jobs state object not showing any field for client name]

Comment: What generates listJobs and why can't you just modify the GraphQL query to the correct one?

Comment: @FINDarkside when I wrote my API structure (and consequently the dynamoDB database structure) in my **schema.graphql** file, the graphQL queries were generated for me by the amplify CLI. Docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/react/start/getting-started/data-model/#create-a-graphql-api-and-database